# ui-grid using external Pagination and exporting data

Tags: angularjs, pagination, export-to-csv, angular-ui-grid

I am currently using ui-grid implemented with external pagination to display my data.  I've run into as issue where I can only export the currently viewed data, however I need to be able to export ALL data as well.

Anyone know a work around to export all data using external pagination?

Comment: What does pagination have to do with the data? Is the data pulled in X amount of rows at a time?

Comment: Yes, and since it's external I'm doing a query to decide what data to display...so when I try to export all data I need to be able to do another query to grab all data...just not sure how/where to implement this with ui-grid.

Comment: I don't think you'd use ui-grid to get the data. I'm not sure of your data source, but can't you just get the data from whatever server side script you're using with plain ole `$http.get()`?

Comment: I'm using the ui-grid menu to export data...I don't know how to implement a customized http.get call using the existing ui-grid menu.  I was hoping someone had an example of how to do this.  Here is the native ui-grid export that I am using: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data

Comment: what the datasource of your table?

Comment: I'm making WFS calls to geoserver, but this shouldn't matter...it's a question of where do I implement the customized get within the native ui-grid export option

Comment: It does matter because you aren't going to use ui-grid to get all the data. You can use `$http.get('http://yourdatasource.com/api/data.json')` to get all the data.

Comment: Where should this http.get call happen? Here is the native ui-grid export that I am using: ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data

Comment: ah, I see. ui-grid has a built in export function. Well, I found this thread and someone suggested using your own function to get the data like I am suggesting https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1398 PaulL suggests there is a draft export function in 3.0 that alludes to solving this issue, but I cannot locate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using csvExport function included with ui-grid.  I added an "Export All" custom menu item and it works great! Here is my code:

```
gridMenuCustomItems: [
                      {
                        title: 'Export All',
                        action: function ($event) {

                                $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
                                    $scope.gridOptions.totalItems = data.totalFeatures;
                                    $scope.gridOptions.data = data.features;
                                    $timeout(function()
                                            {
                                                var myElement = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location"));
                                                $scope.gridApi.exporter.csvExport( uiGridExporterConstants.ALL, uiGridExporterConstants.ALL, myElement );
                                            }, 1000);

                                    });                                                                                                                                                                     
                        }
                      }
                    ]
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I took ui-grids server side example and modified their plnkr a bit. I simply created a button outside the ui-grid and that button calls your datasource which converts json into CSV and downloads the file

http://plnkr.co/edit/xK3TYtKANuci0kUgGacQ?p=preview

```
<button ng-click="exportAllData()">Export Data</button>
```

then in your controller:

```
$scope.exportAllData = function()
{
  setTimeout(function()
  {
    $http.get('largeLoad.json').success(function(response)
    {       
      $scope.JSONToCSVConvertor(response, "Data Title", true);
    }); 
  },100);
};

$scope.JSONToCSVConvertor = function(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel)
{
  //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
  var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

  var CSV = '';    
  //Set Report title in first row or line

  CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

  //This condition will generate the Label/Header
  if (ShowLabel) {
      var row = "";

      //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
      for (var index in arrData[0]) {

          //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
          row += index + ',';
      }

      row = row.slice(0, -1);

      //append Label row with line break
      CSV += row + '\r\n';
  }

  //1st loop is to extract each row
  for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
      var row = "";

      //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
      for (var index in arrData[i]) {
          row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
      }

      row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

      //add a line break after each row
      CSV += row + '\r\n';
  }

  if (CSV == '') {        
      alert("Invalid data");
      return;
  }   

  //Generate a file name
  var fileName = "MyReport_";
  //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
  fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g,"_");   

  //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
  var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

  // Now the little tricky part.
  // you can use either>> window.open(uri);
  // but this will not work in some browsers
  // or you will not get the correct file extension    

  //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
  var link = document.createElement("a");    
  link.href = uri;

  //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
  link.style = "visibility:hidden";
  link.download = fileName + ".csv";

  //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

`JSONToCSVConverter()` source: http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try and implement your solution within a custom menu item (rather than a button)...I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: if you have questions, let me know. I'll try and help.