# ui-grid exporter with external pagination

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, exporter

My problem is how to export to csv all data with external pagination, not only data on current page

You can find my code for controller and view below.

---

#### My HTML :

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button" ng-click="downloadCSV()">{{exportBtn}}</button>
</div>
```

#### My JS :

In grid preparation I have :

```
...

enableSelectAll: true,
exporterCsvFilename: config.csvFileName,
exporterCsvLinkElement: angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location")),
exporterHeaderFilter : $translate.instant,

//Here is my downloadCSV function
scope.downloadCSV = function () {
    if(scope.gridApi && scope.gridApi.exporter) {
        scope.gridApi.exporter.csvExport(uiGridExporterConstants.ALL,uiGridExporterConstants.ALL);
    }
};
```

---

#### UPDATE :

After some investigation, I found that in `gridOptions.data` I am only getting data for current page.

```
scope.gridOptions.data = data.response.docs;// here i have 20 records
scope.gridOptions.totalItems = data.response.numFound; // number is 50
```

I have pagging and I am showing 20 records per page. So exporter only sees 20 records in grid and exports only the..So how can we export all data in these case?

Comment: did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967782/ui-grid-using-external-pagination-and-exporting-data?rq=1

Comment: Well i am using uigridexporterconstants.ALL and i don't want to use menu from ui grid.  I call downloadCSV function from button outside ui-grid